# pandas maximum number of decimal places using float64

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I have a code where i read a data set as strings and what to convert it to float. As a string the values are something like this (The unit is Angstrom):

```
-11.22221784
```

when i now covert it via:

```
cols=[....a list of columns i want to convert]

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
```

the value will become rounded to:

```
-11.222218
```

which i do not want!!
if i convert it via

```
....
import decimal as D

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].astype(D.Decimal)
```

i get the correct value in my dataframe but i can not plot the data as the dtype panas sees is object.

Comment: A `float` should hold 17 decimal places. It's possible that the value is rounded when you output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is rendering the column with 6 decimal places, it's storing it correctly:

```
In [11]: pd.Series([-11.22221784])
Out[11]:
0   -11.222218
dtype: float64

In [12]: pd.Series([-11.22221784])[0]
Out[12]: -11.22221784
```

Comment: Indeed that was the case! Thank you very much for your help! It is really appreciated!